# should i be using threads multiprocessing or asycio for my project?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to build a temperature control module that can be controlled over a network or with manual controls. the individual parts of my program all work but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make them all work together.also my temperature control module is python and the client is C#.

so far as physical components go i have a keypad that sets a temperature and turns the heater on and off and an lcd screen that displays temperature data and of course a temperature sensor.

for my network stuff i need to:
constantly send temperature data to the client. 
send a list of log files to the client.
await prompts from the client to either set the desired temperature or send a log file to the client.

so far all the hardware works fine and each individual part of the network functions work but not together. I have not tried to use both physical and network components.

I have been attempting to use threads for this but was wondering if i should be using something else?

EDIT:
here is the basic logic behind what i want to do:

Hardware:

keypad takes a number inputs until '*' it then sets a temp variable.

temp variable is compared to sensor data and the heater is turned on or off accordingly.

'#' turns of the heater and sets temp variable to 0.

sensor data is written to log files while temp variable is not 0

Network:

upon client connect the client is sent a list of log files

temperature sensor data is continuously sent to client.

prompt handler listens for prompts.

if client requests log file the temperature data is halted and the file sent after which the temperature data is resumed.

client can send a command to the prompt handler to set the temp variable to trigger the heater

client can send a command to the prompt handler to stop the heater and set temp variable to 0

commands from either the keypad or client should work at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing is generally for when you want to take advantage of the computational power of multiple processing cores. Multiprocessing limits your options on how to handle shared state between components of your program, as memory is copied initially on process creation, but not shared or updated automatically. Threads execute from the same region of memory, and do not have this restriction, but cannot take advantage of multiple cores for computational performance. Your application does not sound like it would require large amounts of computation, and simply would benefit from concurrency to be able to handle user input, networking, and a small amount of processing at the same time. I would say you need threads not processes. I am not experienced enough with asyncio to give a good comparison of that to threads.

Edit: This looks like a fairly involved project, so don't expect it to go perfectly the first time you hit "run", but definitely very doable and interesting.

Here's how I would structure this project...

I see effectively four separate threads here (maybe small ancillary dameon threads for stupid little tasks)

1. I would have one thread acting as your temperature controller (PID control / whatever) that has sole control of the heater output. (other threads get to make requests to change setpoint / control mode (duty cycle / PID))
2. I would have one main thread (with a few dameon threads) to handle the data logging: Main thead listens for logging commands (pause, resume, get, etc.) dameon threads to poll thermometer, rotate log files, etc..
3. I am not as familiar with networking, and this will be specific to your client application, but I would probably get started with `http.server` just for prototyping, or maybe something like `websockets` and a little bit of `asyncio`. The main thing is that it would interact with the data logger and temperature controller threads with getters and setters rather than directly modifying values
4. Finally, for the keypad input, I would likely just make up a quick `tkinter` application to grab keypresses, because that's what I know. Again, form a request with the tkinter app, but don't modify values directly; use getters and setters when "talking" between threads. It just keeps things better organized and compartmentalized.

Comment: @drako234 perhaps you could write up some pseudocode or draw up a diagram of your subsystems, and then I could take a shot at what threads I might allocate to various tasks. This is very much a "the devil's in the details" problem, so I think a great way to approach it is a block diagram of your framework of individual components that all need to work together

Comment: @drako234 I added some more specific implementation suggestions.. You could definitely burninate some of the complexity for your first iterations to keep it more managable (I would start by simplifying your logging situation). Part of the benefit of keeping separate threads so isolated (using getters and setters) is that it's easier to modify a single component without affecting the others.